# jQuery datepicker won't change the year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm having a jQuery datepicker that has `'yearRange'=>':2020'`.

So here's the situation:
the date in the control is set to the past: 11th year.

[image: datepicker starting from now]

When I open datepicker to set the date in the future but in the current year (same 13th) I don't have to change the year in the dropdown list and I see the 13th year selected. But in fact it's still that 11th year.

[image: 11th year selected]

So. How do I fix this problem? Is this a bug or what?

Comment: I think the year (and the whole date) will be updated as soon as you click on some calendar date cell. I.e. changing the year in dropdown is not really selecting date yet.

Comment: did you find the solution you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the date right after initializing from js, example:

```
$('#ddd').datepicker({
    yearRange: "2011:2020",
    changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
});
$( "#ddd" ).datepicker( "setDate", "6/14/2020" );
```

check this working example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/78Vvx/1/)

and this one with a text box : [jsfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/78Vvx/2/)

Comment: This will change the date in the input. I don't want it to be changed unless I do it in the ui control.

Comment: this sets the range of years between 2011 and 2020 and sets the default date to 6/14/2020 ,,if you don't want to set a default date just remove the last line